# Spring Boot templates not resolved

Tags: spring, maven, thymeleaf, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a standalone web application using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. The application runs fine from IntelliJ IDEA, but I'm not able to run the jar on its own. Apparently the templates are not included.

My project is structured as follows:

```
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── my
│       │       └── domain
│       │           └── application
│       │               ├── domain
│       │               ├── service
│       │               ├── web
│       │               ├── ApplicationConfig.java
│       │               ├── SecurityConfig.java
│       │               ├── ThymeleafConfig.java
│       │               └── WebConfig.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   ├── application.properties
│       │   └── log4j.properties
│       └── webapp
│           ├── resources
│           │   ├── jquery.js
│           │   └── style.css
│           └── WEB-INF
│               └── views
│                   ├── layout.html
│                   ├── login.html
│                   └── menu.html
└── pom.xml
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
}

@Bean
public SessionBean sessionBean() {
    return new SessionBean();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
}
```

ThymeleafConfig:

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver() ;
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

WebConfig:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

I managed to include the WEB-INF folder by adding it as resource in pom.xml, but the views are still not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the WEB-INF folder completely and sticking everything in resources as is done in [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content/tree/master/complete/src/main/resources/templates) guide?

Comment: Works fine, thanks! I'm having some problems accessing the static content, but I'll post back if I can't find a solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue accessing static content when I try to use templates. Did you find a resolution to that?

Comment: You should probably create a new question describing your problem if the answer here does not fit you needs

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution. I feel you should be able to specify a path for your templates or else there would be no point on setting the prefix.

Comment: @PedroHoehlCarvalho This is not a workaround. It's just the way Spring Boot works when deploying an uber-jar. If one want's to forgo Spring Boot's conventions, they are welcome to. It's quite easy to do!

Comment: I was under the impression that the user who asked the question was trying to do precisely that. Instead, he was forced to move his files to the default location because he was unable to map "/WEB-INF/views/". I was hoping for an answer that would address this problem.

Comment: When running an uber-jar generally the source `webapps` folder is not even on the compile classpath. I am sure you can get everything to work, but when running a stand-alone jar it doesn't make sense to jump through all those hoops