# Thymeleaf fails on gradle build

Tags: gradle, thymeleaf, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf to build an application, everything works fine in IntelliJ, but when I build via **`gradle clean build`** then I get errors.

Here is my directory structure:

```
 src
├───  generated
├───  main
│   ├───  java
│   ├───  resources
│   │   └───  assets
│   │       ├───  css
│   │       ├───  js
│   │       └───  templates
│   │           └─── *.html
│   └───  webapp
└───  test
    ├───  groovy
    │   └─── unit & integration tests here
    ├───  resources
    └───  unit
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

def generatedResources = "$buildDir/generated-resources/main"

configurations {
    querydslapt
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RC4")
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot"}
    maven {url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.0.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.0.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.0.RC1")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.1.Final")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.3")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1')
    compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1')
    compile('com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0.2')
    compile('com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.3.2')
    compile('com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.3.2')

    querydslapt "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.3.2"
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
}

sourceSets {

    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/generated']
        }
    }
    main {
        //let's register an output folder on the main SourceSet:
    output.dir(generated, builtBy: 'generateQueryDSL')
        java {
            srcDirs = []
        }
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy', 'src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        }

        output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/main"
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = []
        }
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/groovy', 'src/test/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
        }

        output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/test"
    }
}


task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates the QueryDSL query types') {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
    ]
    destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir
}

compileGeneratedJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    options.warnings = false
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

clean {
    delete sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src/main/generated')
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

I have my UI configured as below:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController( "/home" ).setViewName( "index" );
        ...
    } 

    // removed to try and find the css/js/images
    // @Override
    // public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    //     registry.addResourceHandler( "/resources/**" ).addResourceLocations( "/resources/" );
    // }      

    ...
}
```

Here is an example test:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
class TreasuryStatusEvaluatorTest extends Specification {

    @Shared
    def ConfigurableApplicationContext context

    @Shared
    private StatusRepository statusRepository

    void setupSpec() {
        Future future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(
                new Callable() {
                    @Override
                    public ConfigurableApplicationContext call() throws Exception {
                        return (ConfigurableApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(OFAC.class)
                    }
                })
        context = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        treasuryStatusEvaluator = context.getBean(TreasuryStatusEvaluator.class)
        statusRepository = context.getBean(StatusRepository.class)
    }

    void cleanupSpec() {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close()
        }
    }
...
}
```

Here is a typical html page:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>  

    <link href="/resources/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/static/css/ofac.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
...

<script src="/resources/static/js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/static/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

These tests run within IntelliJ or as an application all is well.  But when I run the tests from the command line, I get errors such as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

I see that in spring-boot there is an issue with directory structure with thymeleaf: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/424  and it would seem that a template directory is required.  I am not using any templates, just html.

**Update #1:**
I moved the html under src/main/resources/*

**Update #2:**
I moved the css/js/libs to src/main/resources/static
I tried having them under src/main/static but that didn't work either

Comment: have you tried with the 1.0.0.RELEASE version of spring-boot? 

ive seen some considerable changes between RCs. Im still understanding springboot autoconfig myself, but if you use starter-web, its probably looking for view files at src/main/resources/templates. not sure how intellij is working though, probably some extra configuration is done in intellij correctly.see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770220/spring-boot-templates-not-resolved?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 1.0.1.RELEASE of Spring Boot now, so you should be using that (and it might just fix your problem). Normally, though, I wouldn't expect you would need Thymeleaf configuration as long as you put your templates in "classpath:/templates" (those html files are what Thymeleaf calls "templates"). You can specify the template location using `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` if you want them somewhere else (see [docs here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java)).

If you prefer to configure Thmyeleaf yourself completely then the you need to use the conventional bean name for the template resolver ("defaultTemplateResolver"), so that Boot knows what you are doing. Details are in the [ThymeleafAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java) - some of the features there are explicitly called out in the docs, but this one appears not to be.

Comment: So I changed to 1.0.1.RELEASE, moved all my html, stylesheets, and removed the Bean templateResolver, and Bean templateEngine.  See updated question above.  However, now no CSS/JS/images show up regardless of where I place them under /src/main/resources/.  I now get errors such as "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - "http://localhost:9001/resources/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"  When the web assets were under WEB-INF/ then tomcat could find them, but now those resources, minus the html files, are not found

Comment: Did you check out the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)? I prefer "src/main/resources/static", but it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation link, I think it confirms that I have my assets in the right place (/src/main/resources/static/css...).  I do not have a ServletContext defined, so I assume this means my html should look at root for the js/css/etc.  But regardless of the path I define, or where I put the resources they cannot be found.  I have updated my question with an example html that cannot find the css or javascript.

Comment: The links are wrong (resources/static/css does not exist as a resource mapping). Try /css etc.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling to understand the servlet context.  Will this need to change once I try and create a WAR and deploy?

Comment: It doesn't have to change (the classpath is the classpath, even in a WAR file). If you know you are building a WAR though, why did you start with a JAR?

Comment: For this particular application, embedded Tomcat was the original goal.  However, if that requirement is going to change then I want to make sure I can migrate to a WAR deployment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the same exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

but using SpringBoot 1.2.0-RELEASE, it could be simply that you need to create a directory src/main/resources/templates.

I upgraded from SpringBoot 1.1.9 to 1.2.0 and started getting this exception. Adding the directory fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, if you get this exception and don't want to use `thymeleaf`, you can disable it by using...

***config/application.yml***

```yaml
spring.groovy.template.check-template-location: false
```

More recent versions of spring, will actually tell you this in the stacktrace...

**i.e.**

```yaml
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Groovy configuration, or set spring.groovy.template.check-template-location=false)
```